# Firebase ListAdapter with custom object

Tags: android

I'm trying to using Firebase to manage my ListView.
The problem is that I want to List custom objects called Gruppo that contains other objects and not only String.
Is possible to use FirebaseListAdapter or I have to invent another strategy to update my ListView in real-time on all phones?

Then why if I do:

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("my_app_URL/");
    DatabaseReference rootRef = database.getReference();
    DatabaseReference groups = rootRef.child("groups");
    Query ref = groups;
```

Query is empty and it doesn't take all the children of groups?

Could someone post a good tutorial?
I've already followed this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2J6spwAVP0M

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase is capable of deserializing nodes in an object more complex than a single `String` with some constraints on field names and data structures.
**IE**
In Firebase database:

```
groups: {
    keyGroup1: {
        groupName: "groupOne",
        numParticipants: "2",
        participants: {
            keyPart1: {
               name: "John",
               surname: "Doe"
            },
            keyPart2: {
                name: "Jane",
                surname: "Doe"
            }
        }
    },
    keyGroup2: {
        groupName: "groupTwo",
        numParticipants: "1",
        participants: {
            keyPart1: {
               name: "Chris",
               surname: "Abc"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Android:

```
public class Group {
    private String groupName;
    private int numParticipants;
    private Map<String, Participant> participants;

    // Constructor, getters and setters
}

public class Participant {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    // Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

then you can pass `Group.class` to `FirebaseListAdapter` constructor:

```
 new FirebaseListAdapter<Group>(/* Activity */, Group.class, /* Layout */, /* DatabaseRef */);
```

However if your data structure is very complex it may be safer to use a `ValueEventListener` to manually instantiate objects and a custom `Adapter`.